# New windows not able to acess NWJS modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

If I create a window using window.open on my NWJS application, it seems that this window cannot acess any nodejs or nwjs module at all. How to I work around it?

I use document.write to write the content of the page, because it will be different according to the context in which the code is running.

```
    var fs = require("fs");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(myfolder);
text=text.toString();
    var wndo = window.open("about:blank", "", "scrollbars=1,width=300,height=500");
wndo.moveTo(screen.width/2-250,screen.height/2-175);

    wndo.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Coder</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="editor/style.css"/>
</head>

<input  style="display:none;" name="file" id="fileDialog" type="file" onchange="openeditor()" />
<label class="button button1" for="fileDialog">Open</label>


<input style="display:none;" name="filesave" id="filesave" type="file" onchange="saveeditor()" nwsaveas />
<label class="button button1" for="filesave" >Save</label>

 <div id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script src="editor/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "`+text+`"

</script>

</html>`);
```

inside app.js there is:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';



openeditor=function(){


var fileinput = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var path = fileinput.value;
path=path.toString()

var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, txt) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err)
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=txt
});


}
saveeditor=function(){


var fileinput = document.querySelector('input[id=filesave]');
var path = fileinput.value;

const fs = require("fs")

texto=document.getElementById('content').innerHTML
texto=texto.toString()

    fs.writeFile(path,texto , function (err) {
  if (err) return;
});



}
```

Is there a way to enable node/nwjs modules in that window? And if not, how do I open a new window in my application which has acess to node/nwjs modules and once open, execute code in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part of your opened window that isn't static is `+ text +` ... so, you have an almost static HTML page

Here's something that will work. Create a static page like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Coder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <input  style="display:none;" name="file" id="fileDialog" type="file" onchange="openeditor()" />
    <label class="button button1" for="fileDialog">Open</label>

    <input style="display:none;" name="filesave" id="filesave" type="file" onchange="saveeditor()" nwsaveas />
    <label class="button button1" for="filesave" >Save</label>

    <div id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <script src="editor/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadText(text) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say it's called `otherpage.html` - it's in the same folder as your "main" page too

Now, the javascript in your main page is

```
    var fs = require("fs");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(myfolder);
    text=text.toString();
    var wndo = window.open("otherpage.html", "", "scrollbars=1,width=300,height=500");
    wndo.addEventListener('load', () => {
        wndo.loadText(text);
    });
    wndo.moveTo(screen.width/2-250,screen.height/2-175);
```

So the main page waits for other page to load, and then calls the other page `loadText` to load the text

Comment: Worked perfectly...But why? Why in my code, node and nwjs modules wouldn't work?

Comment: because you open `about:blank` ... whereas I open a page that is "part" of the "nwjs app" :p

Comment: why js/node/nwjs needs so much confuse stuff? ;-; To me anything opened by the main window would be part of the app

Comment: I can see why you wouldn't want external sites accessing nwjs